# How can check variables is null or empty with one function in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-eloquent-resource

I want to check if there is a function in laravel 8 like **IsNullOrEmpty for C#** to check for empty and null value using just one function.

Comment: You can use ``empty()`` You can provide some codes that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `empty()` PHP function.
The `empty()` function checks whether a variable is empty or not.

This function returns false if the variable exists and is not empty, otherwise it returns true.

The following values evaluates to empty:

1. 0
2. 0.0
3. "0"
4. ""
5. FALSE
6. array()
7. NULL

Comment: But when you use eloquent get() function, empty() will not work. empty() returns true for collection and laravel eloquent get() return collection of objects. In this scenario you will have to use collection's isEmpty() or isNotEmpty() functions.